# How to detect collision between two object in same image andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game using andengine.. I want to detect collision between two different object in same image.. Attached dummy image

[image]

Image used: bus.png and dont want to use seperate image for coin. Placed both in same image(bus & coin)

Player will run on top of bus . Need to check whether player hits this coin image or not. ? Its any way to detect collision of coin within same image ?

Answer (score 0):

You can place transparent image as dummy image to  coins and then check for  collision with player. If you Implement physics bodies check at contact listener